# Capybara didn't visit page although Cucumber step succeeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara

I am using Capybara with Cucumber to test my rails application. Given the following scenario:

> Admin adds new administrator
>
> Given I am logged in as admin
>
> When I am on the list admins page
>
> And I follow "add_admin"
>
> .......

When I run this feature, it is successful at the first two steps and fails in the third. When I used

> Then show me the page

It displayed the login page, not the admin's page. I can't understand how it passes by Cucumber where it didn't even login, and can't fix that problem.

Comment: Can you typed Capybara for this `I follow "add_admin"`

Comment: `When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
  click_link(link)
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was because latest changes in Design that makes the buttons unreachable. I figured it out by using Selenium Webdriver.